# Selector for the margin-top and margin-bottom of an element

Tags: css, less

I want to have different :hover cursor in an element, lets say pointer on the element, n-resize for the margin-top, and s-resize for the margin bottom. I know I can make a different div before and after the span element to have the selector that. The problem is, the tree HTML is auto-generated from a JS library (fancytree, a tree library), I'm afraid if I manually insert another element before and after the span, the functionality will breaks. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the following image explaining the situation.

[image]

Here's my LESS code as suggested by one of the comment, it doesn't work.

```
span.fancytree-node {
    /* See #117 */
    display: inherit; // #117, resolves to 'display: list-item;' for standard trees
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: @fancy-node-v-spacing;
    margin-bottom: @fancy-node-v-bottom-spacing;
    min-height: @fancy-line-height;
    cursor: pointer;
    :before {
        cursor: n-resize;
    }
    :after {
        cursor: s-resize;
    }
}
```

To make it more clear, I need the margin, I can't add another element above and below the element, because that margin is used by my JS library to detect drag n drop placement.

Comment: you can work with :before and :after

Comment: it doesn't works, with either double colon or single colon, I'll edit my answer to provide my LESS code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make the parent of the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements `position: relative`
- Make the two pseudo-elements `position: absolute` and position with `top` / `right` / `bottom` and `left`.

  - Using both `left` and `right` will stretch the element between the left and right edges of the parent.
- Use a negative `top` or `bottom` value that is equal to the value of the margins so that the pseudo-elements are placed over the margin of their parent. Their heights will be the same as well.

#### Example

> **Note:** It's possible the pseudo-elements may interfere with the JS drag and drop. That's not possible to test with what we can re-create from the question. There may be a better solution that involves changing the pointers with JS.

```css
div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  cursor: n-resize;
  content: '';/*Needed to show the pseudo-elements*/
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;/*Same as margin*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 10px;/*Same as margin*/
}
div:after {
  cursor: s-resize;
  top: initial;
  bottom: -10px;/*Same as margin*/
}
```

```html
<div>Item</div>
```

Comment: Works wonderful. So my initial assumption to not add elements is wrong, sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to position the `:before` pseudoelement relative to its parent container. Like this:

```
div.box {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;

}
div.box:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px; //LOOK HERE
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: n-resize;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help me :) but I already used the chosen answer.